# How to list DB data like this in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It's easy to list data in rows.

controller:

```
return View(XXX.ToList());
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCPROJECT.Models.TABLE1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <table style="width: 100%">
            ........
            .....
            </table>
        }
```

But how can I list data like this in a viewpage in MVC4?

[image]

Comment: where - in a view or else?

Comment: @DanielA.White In a Viewpage. :)

Comment: you can use [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)

Comment: its known as Pivoting .. Refer to these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147059/convert-list-to-a-pivot-list  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963491/pivot-data-using-linq ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your data structure, you could simply do the following (assuming your Model doesn't have a lot of items in it):

**EDIT:** As requested in comments, I've added it so each header row only contains 5 items:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <th>@item.Id</th>
            @if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:</tr><tr>
            }
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@* some data on item *@</td>
        </tr>     
    }
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. but how to set 5-columns a row? the 6th item.id must display on the second row.

Comment: @user951581 Check my updated edit. I've added a 5 column row.