# Show data from horizontal to vertical view in grid c#- wpf-xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to assign Header control of column to Row header in wpf-xaml.Am having a list of datas populated in grid.Now its showing in horizontal way.I want to show that in vertical view..In grid.

Am having a grid with values like below.

### NAME|AGE|ADDRESS|PINCODE|NATIONALITY|

A   |25 |ABC    |4545445|ABCD       |
B   |26 |BCD    |1221211|BCDE       |
C   |27 |CDE    |4345444|CDEF       |
D   |28 |DEF    |3335445|DEFG       |

And I want this to be shown like this.

---

### NAME        |A  |B  |C  |D

AGE     |25 |26 |27 |28
ADDRESS     |ABC    |BCD    |CDE    |DEF
PINCODE     |4545445|1221211|4345444|3335445
NATIONALITY |ABCD   |BCDE   |CDEF   |DEFG

Database calls cant be changed.I will be getting a list of records.And these records view wants to be changed from Horizontal to vertical view.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question more clear. 
Please post some sample code as well.
Please read before posting again - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF horizontal DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147059/convert-list-to-a-pivot-list)

Comment: yes...that works for me...thankyou..